# JTable use RowFilter to compare two columns

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTable` with a certain number of columns (all String). I would like to implement a filter that shows only the rows where the column2 and the column3 containing the same string.
Is it possible? I tried with the regExp but I don't see the way to compare table cell values.

Answer (score 3):

simply implement RowFilter directly:

```
  RowFilter filter = new RowFilter<Object, Integer>() {

       @Override
       public boolean include(Entry entry) {
            return entry.getValue(firstColumn).equals(entry.getValue(secondColumn));
       }
  }
```

(null checks and full generics omitted)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RowFilter that compares the data in both columns to each other.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

```
     //col as int is in outer class. Pls note col is your column to specify.
     //So if you want more columns use || and with another column say col2.
     class Columnfilter  extends RowFilter<Object, Integer>
     { String txt=null;
     Columnfilter(String txt){
          this.txt=txt;
      }

      void setText(String txt){
            this.txt=txt;
      }

   @Override
   public boolean include(Entry entry) {

       if(txt==null)return false;
        if(col==-1)return true;//for all
     String colVal=  entry.getStringValue(col);//chk column if value exist
        int b= colVal.toLowerCase().indexOf(txt.toLowerCase());

        if(b!=-1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
   }}
```